# How to add a select all checkbox

Tags: cakephp, formhelper

I have this line:

```
echo $form->input('management_categories',array('options' => $instrumentCategoriesManagement,'type' => 'select','multiple' => 'checkbox','selected' => $management_categories));
```

How can I add an additional checkbox that says "Select all" at the beginning?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it works for checkbox:

```
echo $form->input('management_categories',array('options' => $instrumentCategoriesManagement,'type' => 'select','multiple' => 'checkbox','selected' => $management_categories,'empty'=>'Select all'));
```

To actually achieve the effect, you'll need to write js code.

Comment: Thnx i didn't know the empty parameter. The js code is written but I didn't want to append the select all checkbox with js.